# Removing suffix automatically from field names using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, typeerror, rename

I have a big layer with thousands of points. It has also dozens of fields in the attribute table. The field names in the attribute tables have all the a suffix `_2`.

I know I can use the "Refractor fields tool" to rename fields, but I want to automate the process to use it on other layers (I have hundreds of other layers with the same issue).

Is there a way to select the layer and have a Python code that remove all those `_2` suffixes from the fields?

I tried the below code from @Taras below:

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('your_layer_name')[0]
fs = layer.fields()
d = {e:1 if f.type() == 10 else 0 for e,f in enumerate(fs)}

string_to_erase = '_02'

with edit(layer):
    for row in layer.getFeatures():
        data = row.attributes()
        for i, val in enumerate(data):
            if d[i] == 1 and string_to_erase in val:
                data[i] = val.replace(string_to_erase, '')
            else:
                pass
        row.setAttributes(data)
        layer.updateFeature(row)
```

However, I obtained an error related to Python:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "J:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.18\apps\Python37\lib\code.py",
> line 90, in runcode exec(code, self.locals)   
>
> File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
>
> File "<string>", line 11, in <module> TypeError: argument of type 'QVariant' is not iterable
> ```

I need help debugging the error. I am using QGIS 3.18.

Comment: @Taras Thanks but I am getting an error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.18\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'QVariant' is not iterable`

Comment: Added the code to the question. Waiting for the question to re-open, Thanks

Comment: Question title is "Remove prefix automatically" but body content of your question is about suffix. Should you not correct your question? Could do it but not sure why you mentioned prefix

Comment: fixed it is the suffix and not prefix! Thx for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two other approaches at least can be used.

The first one with ["Refactor fields"](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#refactor-fields) called from PyQGIS. Drawbacks: not in place, generate a new layer but keep fields "in place". You can always replace your original layer with this one but more code, not included here.

```py
import processing

def remove_suffix(text, suffix):
    if text.endswith(suffix):
        return text[:-len(suffix)]
    return text

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('your_layer_name')[0]
mappings = [{
    "precision": field.precision(),
    "expression": f"\"{field.name()}\"",
    "name": remove_suffix(field.name(), '_2'),
    "length": field.length(),
    "type": field.type()
} for field in layer.fields()]

result = processing.run("native:refactorfields", {
    'INPUT': layer,
    'FIELDS_MAPPING': mappings,
    'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
})

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(result['OUTPUT'])
```

Second approach: use field renaming instead of playing at feature level like you've choose. Drawback: renamed fields got to the end of the fields list. See below code for an example

```py
def remove_suffix(text, suffix):
    if text.endswith(suffix):
        return text[:-len(suffix)]
    return text

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('your_layer_name')[0]
# layer = iface.activeLayer()
fields = layer.fields()
fieldNames = fields.names()

with edit(layer):
    for idx, field_name in enumerate(fieldNames):
        print(field_name)
        old_name = field_name
        new_name = remove_suffix(field_name, "_2")
        if old_name != new_name:
            layer.renameAttribute(idx , new_name)
    layer.updateFields()
```

Comment: I like this part `return text  # or whatever` =)

Comment: Remaining of borrowed code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891340/remove-a-prefix-from-a-string (but changed to use `endswith` instead of `startswith`). Cleaned

Comment: More about being lazy. Doing Python since more than 10 years so was not complex...

Comment: @ThomasG77 both proposed solutions are great and flexible. Thank you.
Taras Thank you also for the code.

Comment: @wollyka you are welcome!